# Is there a way to calculate a program's time complexity in milliseconds?

Tags: c++, time, complexity-theory, milliseconds

Well, I wanted to compare the time efficiency of 2 programs, which are designed to do the same thing. I want some function/script/method, so that after the execution of a program, it gives me the time required to do that process. like - `"The program took 0.3ms to complete"`. 
I had searched for threads with similar topic,but i was not satisfied with what i read. So any light on this topic is appreciated!

Comment: Complexity isn't measured in milliseconds.

Comment: you could use `getWindowsTick()` @DeadMG I agree, but what he wants is clear, although he used the wrong words. also , when we just started learning our teacher used MS to compare different students algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to measure execution time you can:

1. Use [boost timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/timer/doc/index.html)
2. Retrieve system time before and after execution and compare

Comment: Thanks For The Quick Reply. Will Definitely Use It. :D

Comment: @nogard: you might want to edit your link - it's pointing to a page that says the interface is deprecated.

Comment: @PrasannaChoudhari: that's not what I wrote. The page exists, but the text on the page tells you not to use that interface anymore. And provides a link to the real interface.